# How to handle two different HttpPost in one controller

Tags: controller, routes, asp.net-web-api

I've got a generic controller with

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void Create(T entity)
 {
    ...
 }
```

and an extra controller wich inherits from the generic controller and has got this method in it:

```
[ActionName("AddPrivileges")]
public void AddPrivileges(AddPrivilegeModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

My problem now is, that the controller has two `HttpPost` requests in it. I tried to fix it with routing, but I think I did something terrible wrong.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "RoleActionRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/Role2/AddPrivileges"
);
```

What can or should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide the special mapping like this

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "SpecialAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/AddPrivileges",
    defaults: new { action = "AddPrivileges" }
    , constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) }
    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "PostAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
    defaults: new { action = "Create" }
    , constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) }
    );
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

So, your special method `AddPrivileges` has now special mapping

Comment: Still no post method when i post a json for creating a new entity, just a internal server error. Edit: when i comment out my AddPrivileges method, i can post a json and it was created.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to map also the default one. So now, the Create would be used, if the pure Controller is called (`api/entityName/`), Addprivileges if the URI contains that method (`api/entityName/Addprivileges `)